Verifying all objects in a Kotlin collection match without overriding equals
I am working on a kotlin function that needs to verify that all objects in a collection have the same value for a particular property. Normally I would simply use distinctBy() and check that the size of the resulting list is <= 1. However, this particular function has an added complication. Two of the possible values need to be treated as 'matching' even though they have different values for the field being compared. I don't want to override the 'equals' method since the logic only applies in this particular function. I could also brute force the problem and simply do a manual comparison of every object in the list against every other item but that doesn't seem very efficient. What other options do I have?
For reference my data model looks like this:
internal enum class IdocsDocumentOwner(val idocsCode: Int, val ownerType: String) {
    Student(2, "Student"),
    Spouse(3, "Student Spouse"),
    Parent1(5, "Father"),
    Parent2(6, "Mother"),
    NonCustodialParent(7, "Noncustodial"),
    Other(8, "Other");
}

I then have a validation function like:
fun validateIdocsGroupFiles( owners:List<IdocsDocumentOwner> ){
    
    val distinctOwners = owners.distinctBy { it.owner.idocsCode }
    assert(distinctOwners.count() <= 1)
    //[Student,Student] == true
    //[Student,Parent1] == false
    //[Parent1,Parent2] == true
}


Why would you ever bother using distinctBy and doing hashing and all that?  Just select the value for the first element of owners, then test that every other element in owners matches it.

Create a function that maps Parent1 and Parent2 to the same number:
fun customMapping(v: IdocsDocumentOwner) = when(v) {
    Parent1, Parent2 -> -1  // make sure no other idocsCode is this number
    else -> v.idocsCode
}

and then use it like this:
    val distinctOwners = owners.distinctBy { customMapping(it) }


Of course, you don't need to make it a separate function; you can just call distinctBy{ when (it) {…} } directly.  (A separate function would be good if you might need to use this comparison elsewhere; otherwise, it's probably not justified.)
